# Organizing Journeys

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have tons of journeys that are accumulating and I'm not able to move them and organize them in separate folder. What is the best way to deal/organize them?

Comment: you should be able to just drag and drop them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go into Journey Dashboard, click Folders, then you should have the ability to drag and drop. Without clicking "Folders" it doesn't let you drag and drop. Annoying UI issue

Comment: It works indeed, thanks Noor. I noticed we can click "organize" when saving the journey and then choose the folder.